# hive sql:extract last 12 months rows

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

There is a column "month" with type string and its values are like:

```
+--------+
| month  |
+--------+
| 201507 |
| 201803 |
| 201602 |
| 201709 |
+--------+
```

Someone familiar with hive time manipulation please tell me how to extract last 12 months rows according to month field.

Comment: This column has year too. I think you need to write [UDF](https://dzone.com/articles/writing-custom-hive-udf-andudaf) for this and extract the result, process the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
where cast(substring(month, 1, 4) || '-' || substring(month, 5, 2) || '-01' as date) >= add_months(current_date, -12)
```

Comment: thanks in advance.I got what you want,but the syntax isn't right

Answer (score 2):

As of Hive 4.0.0, `add_months` supports an optional argument `output_date_format`:  `add_months(string start_date, int num_months, output_date_format)`.

```
select month 
  from table 
 where month >= add_months(current_date, -12,'yyyyMM');
```

Before Hive 4.0.0:

```
select month 
      from table 
     where month >= date_format(add_months(current_date, -12),'yyyyMM');
```